# Como tratar con molesto mensaje JS?

Tags: php, javascript

En mi pagina tengo varios modales que se muestran después de ser redireccionado tras cumplirse ciertas condiciones. El problema es que cuando hago click en cualquier elemento de la pagina que no me envié hacia otra pagina, console me arroja este mensaje: **Uncaught ReferenceError: session is not defined
    at clickfueraSession**  Esto no me afecta negativamente al funcionamiento de la pagina ya que todo funciona como debe, pero es muy molesto ver como este mensaje sigue apareciendo en console, asi que me gustaria pedir su ayuda para tratar con este problemita, les dejo el codigo:

PHP

```
 <?php 
      if (isset($_GET['alert']) && $_GET['alert']=="iniciar_Session") {
    ?>
    <div class="sessionModal" id="session">
      <div class="contenidoModal" id="contenidoCaducado">
        <div class="modalHeader">
          <h2>¡Debes registrate o iniciar Session!</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modalBody">
          <p>Debes estar registrado o iniciar session para poder comprar.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modalFooter">
          <h2>diseñosweb</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

JS

```
var modalSession = document.getElementById('session');

window.addEventListener('click', clickfueraSession);

 function clickfueraSession(e){
   if (e.target == session) {
   session.style.display = 'none';
   }
  }
```

Comment: donde declaraste la variable session?

Comment: bastaría con reemplazar `session` con `modalSession` en la función `clickfueraSession`

Comment: hola amenadiel gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente remplazar session con modalSession solucione el problema con ese molesto mensaje.